# problem with installing gdb on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, gdb, debian

I try to install gdb on my Kali Linux, I downloaded compressed file from official site, after decompressing file I have tons of file and I don't know what to with them.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried to read files README but nothing was in there. Please help me with installing gdb.

Also I tried with apt-get install gdb, but some errors occured. They say something like:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/e/elfutils/libdebuginfod-common_0.187-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/e/elfutils/libdw1_0.187-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/e/elfutils/libelf1_0.187-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/b/babeltrace/libbabeltrace1_1.5.8-2+b1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/e/elfutils/libdebuginfod1_0.187-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/s/source-highlight/libsource-highlight-common_3.1.9-4.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/b/boost1.74/libboost-regex1.74.0_1.74.0-16_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
and few more
```

I don't know what to do with these errors...

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install gdb` ?,
I can see it as a [debian package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gdb)

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update` before any other apt command. This updates your local copy of the package list. Package servers typically have only the most recent version of each package.

Comment: While updating I get this message:            W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://kali.koyanet.lv/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository

Comment: I have an information about some broken package while upgrading also. Is there any way to fix it? I am totally new to this and it is a little overwhelming.